# Parse a json file and add the strings to a URL

Tags: python

How do I parse a json output get the list from data only and then add the output into say google.com/confidetial and the other strings in the list.
so my json out put i will name it "text"

```
text = {"success":true,"code":200,"data":["Confidential","L1","Secret","Secret123","foobar","maret1","maret2","posted","rontest"],"errs":[],"debugs":[]}.
```

What I am looking to do is get the list under data only. so far the script i got is giving me the entire json out put.

```
json.loads(text)
print text 
output = urllib.urlopen("http://google.com" % text)
print output.geturl()
print output.read()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jsonobj = json.loads(text)
print jsonobj['data']
```

Will print the list in the `data` section of your JSON.

If you want to open each as a link after `google.com`, you could try this:

```
def processlinks(text):
    output = urllib.urlopen('http://google.com/' % text)
    print output.geturl()
    print output.read()

map(processlinks, jsonobj['data'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
info = json.loads(text)
json_text = json.dumps(info["data"])
```

Using `json.dumps` converts the python data structure gotten from `json.loads` back to regular json text.

So, you could then use `json_text` wherever you were using `text` before and it should only have the selected key, in your case: `"data"`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this where `result` is your JSON data:

```
from itertools import product

base_domains = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.example.com']
result = {"success":True,"code":200,"data":["Confidential","L1","Secret","Secret123","foobar","maret1","maret2","posted","rontest"],"errs":[],"debugs":[]}
for path in product(base_domains, result['data']):
    print '/'.join(path) # do whatever

http://www.google.com/Confidential
http://www.google.com/L1
http://www.google.com/Secret
http://www.google.com/Secret123
http://www.google.com/foobar
http://www.google.com/maret1
http://www.google.com/maret2
http://www.google.com/posted
http://www.google.com/rontest
http://www.example.com/Confidential
http://www.example.com/L1
http://www.example.com/Secret
http://www.example.com/Secret123
http://www.example.com/foobar
http://www.example.com/maret1
http://www.example.com/maret2
http://www.example.com/posted
http://www.example.com/rontest
```

Comment: I had done that before but since the list in json changes from time to time I wanted to parse the results without hard coding the list into the script.

Comment: @user2548131 don't hard code the list... `result = json.loads(text)` or however you're getting the data...

Comment: I like this example so say i want the json string from each of the urls to be printed how do i go about it ?